# Classes not pushed to bin folder - eclipse spring boot

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot project. Whenever I make a change & run as spring boot app , the latest changes are not reflecting. This was working fine for past 3-4 month and I started seeing this issue in the past couple of days. I have been trying to unsuccessfully find the change that may have triggered this issue. For instance , I change the application.properties and run a gradle build. I see the latest application.properties in build folder but the old one in the bin folder. So I am having to manually copy all the modified files under bin folder before running the project as spring app. Can you please suggest as to how I can investigate this further? Thanks.

EDIT: This seems to be impact one specific application and not all the applications in the workspace.

Comment: Did you try by removing Eclipse settings files and folders and reimporting your project again?

Comment: I checked out afresh and created a new workspace. But all the developers in the project seem to hit the same issue.

Comment: Same issues. Usually removing settings and importing the project again solves the issue, but this isn't a solution since it happens quite often.

Comment: I checked out the same source code in a new installation of STS in a different machine and it worked fine. Still unable to figure out the root cause.